# How can I make condition inside the geometry options?

Tags: conditionals

I would like to make condition inside the geometry options

```
 \geometry
 { headsep    =   \baselineskip
  , textwidth  = 42\baselineskip
  , textheight = 60\baselineskip
  , hmarginratio = 2:3
  , vmarginratio = 2:3
  , bindingoffset = 0cm
  , onecolumn
 }
```

I try the code bellow, but that does not work.

```
\newif\ifPDF \PDFtrue
\geometry
 { headsep    =   \baselineskip
 , textwidth  = 42\baselineskip
 , textheight = 60\baselineskip
 \ifPDF
 , hmarginratio = 1:1
 \else
 , hmarginratio = 2:3
 \fi
 , vmarginratio = 2:3
 , bindingoffset = 0cm
 , onecolumn
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use conditionals inside the options in that way. However you can exploit the fact that `\geometry` can appear as many times as you want.

```
\newif\ifscreen
\screentrue % comment out for printable version

\geometry{
  headsep=\baselineskip,
  textwidth=42\baselineskip,
  textheight=60\baselineskip,
  heightrounded,
  vmarginratio=2:3,
  onecolumn,
}
\ifscreen
  \geometry{
    hmarginratio=1:1,
  }
\else
  \geometry{
    hmarginratio=2:3,
  }
\fi
```

I think you *can* do

```
hmarginratio=\ifscreen 1:1\else 2:3\fi,
```

but I don't think it's even worth trying.

Comment: Please can you explain why the second (shorter) answer is not worth trying? It works :)

Comment: @chejnik Yes, I suspected it works `;-)`, but I think it's unreadable and difficult to maintain if the option is buried in the middle of several others.

Comment: I see, thank you for explanation and the answer.